# Unable to render icon from font library with actioncolumn and iconCls

Tags: css, extjs, sass, extjs4.2

I have the following in index.html for FontAwesome:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

An item in grid as:

```
{
    text: 'Add',
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    flex: 1,
    align: 'center',
    items: [{
        iconCls: 'icon-circle-up',
        tooltip: 'above this'
    },{
        iconCls: 'icon-circle-down',
        tooltip: 'below this'
    }]
}
```

And finally the related scss as:

```
.icon-circle-up {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0aa";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon-circle-down {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0ab";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

When the grid is rendered, I see the placeholders for icons and tooltip, but icons are not rendered. 
One of the icons has the following as it is rendered:

```
<img role="button" alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0  icon-circle-up" data-qtip="above this">
```

What's wrong here? Is it unable to get icon from font stylesheet? How can I get the icon?

Please note that other "image" components on the page work fine with 'glyph' using FontAwesome.

Comment: What does the compiled CSS look like?  Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677306/sass-3-4-1-escaping-a-270e-into-270e-which-breaks-a-font-icon

Comment: Updated with the rendered source. It is: <img role="button" alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0  icon-circle-up" data-qtip="Add new driver above this">

Comment: What does Chrome DevTools say ? Do the css selectors apply to the html class ?

Comment: Yes they do. The class "icon-circle-up" that I applied is applied and as observed on Chrome, has the following: 
.icon-circle-up {
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: "\f0aa";
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: Is the problem not with "src" having incorrect value here?

Comment: Have you looked at your console to verify that stylesheet is actually being loaded?

Comment: Yes, it does get loaded. Other fields that have icons from the stylesheet work fine.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not possible because ExtJS renders the action buttons as 'img' tags. If you don't provide an 'icon' parameter the image you see in the html code is an empty gif of 1x1 pixels.

But @qdev found a workaround here:
[Font-Awesome ExtJS ActionColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573608/font-awesome-extjs-actioncolumn)

Instead of

```
icon: ...,
```

you write

```
glyph: 'xf0aa@FontAwesome',
```

I just made a fiddle for ExtJS 4.2 for that. Works quite nice: http://jsfiddle.net/mmfs3678/3/

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was likely asked for ExtJS 5, but for anyone using ExtJS 6 and above, the issue could be that the `fontCls` parameter is missing.

In ExtJS 6, `iconCls` is specified with the following notation:

```
iconCls: '{fontCls} {iconPrefix}-{iconName}'
```

So, rather than just `fa-home`, try specifying `x-fa fa-home`, as below:

```
iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home'
```

[image: Available ExtJS Font Packages]

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/font_ext.html